# MongoDB: operation exceeded time limit

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use `$out` to create collection:

```js
db.books.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'book_copies', 
      localField: 'ISBN10',
      foreignField: 'book_id',
      as: 'book_copies'
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ISBN10: 1,
      ISBN13:1,
      Title: 1,
      Cover: 1,
      Publisher: 1,
      Pages: 1,
      Authors_arr: 1,
      "book_copies.branch_id": 1,
      "book_copies.no_of_copies": 1
    }
  }
]);
```

Code above is running without error in MongoShell.

However, if I tried to do this:

```js
db.books.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'book_copies', 
      localField: 'ISBN10',
      foreignField: 'book_id',
      as: 'book_copies'
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ISBN10: 1,
      ISBN13:1,
      Title: 1,
      Cover: 1,
      Publisher: 1,
      Pages: 1,
      Authors_arr: 1,
      "book_copies.branch_id": 1,
      "book_copies.no_of_copies": 1
    }
  },
  { $out: 'newCollection' }
]);
```

It returns error of operation exceeded time limit.

It is a large collection with 25000 documents. Is it because the collection is too large?
How can I avoid this error?

---

Question resolved by creating index on Book_id and ISBN10

Comment: did you use `await` in your query?

Comment: OP mentions they are running this in the shell, so `await` shouldn't be related here. Without using `$out`, the database is going to return just the initial batch of results, which presumably is much larger (and takes longer) than the initial batch. You'll want to run this without specifying a timeout. I don't think the shell adds a timeout by default itself, maybe you are using the shell in Compass which might?

Comment: @Stacks Queue. Nope, I did not.

Comment: @user20042973. I tried to do the same things on compass and set max time as 2000000, but didn't run. Also, I tried it without specifying a timeout, still not work...